# URL rewriting using htaccess and PHP

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter

I'm a beginner to htaccess. I have a url

```
www.example.com/article/details?id=2&category=sports&subcategory=cricket&url=ricky-ponting
```

I'm trying to rewrite this URL in htaccess.
I want the above url should be formatted as:

```
www.example.com/sports/cricket/ricky-ponting
```

**I want to hide article, details and id from the URL**

I don't know how to create this URL. Is it possible to handle the hidden ID parameter in URL in backend using PHP?

Thanks in advance. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: I think you've confused rewrite with redirect

Comment: are you using a front controller pattern? if so, just use a routing library

Comment: yes you are using codeigniter, this should be possible without messing with .htaccess. See here https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/routing.html

Comment: @delboy1978uk I'm using codeigniter framework. I won't able to create front controller for every dynamic categories like sports/cricket, world/discovery etc

Comment: Codeigniter uses index.php as a front controller already, so you don't need to worry about that. Just look into the routing component.

Comment: @delboy1978uk I don't want to show ID on the url.

Comment: then don't? use something else you can use as a unique identity

Comment: Only unique identity is ID, but it should be hidden from URL. Client send me a reference like this www.example.com/article/world/2018/05/21/ricky-ponting.html. Here unique id is not showing anywhere.

Comment: You can redirect your `url` in cPanel

Comment: If you don't want to use id, then don't, but you need another way to uniquely identify what you're looking for, as the others above have stated.  In your last comment, `world/2018/05/21/ricky-ponting` all of that is what's unique (I assume category, then dates, then an article `slug` in the articles controller.  You'd be better off turning off the get query and building the URLs like you want, then you don't have to deal with .htaccess or any other ways that CI can actually handle on it's own.

Answer (score -1):

Put a htaccess file in project root by following code.

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
RewriteEngine on                       
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|(.*)\.swf|forums|images|css|downloads|js|robots\.txt|favicon\.ico)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ./index.php?$1 [L,QSA]
```

now you can customize your url.
User your get parameter after controller and method. 
like: www.example.com/article/details/sports/cricket/ricky-ponting